# python pandas: Find top n and then m in the top n

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like the following:

```
fastmoving[['dist','unique','id']]
Out[683]: 
        dist  unique          id
1   0.406677     4.0  4.997434e+09
2   0.406677     4.0  4.452593e+09
5   0.406677     4.0  4.188395e+09
1   0.434386     4.0  8.288070e+09
4   0.434386     4.0  3.274609e+09
```

What I want to achieve is to:

1. Find top n longest-distance entries. Column 'dist'
2. Find which ids have the largest percentage m in the top n entries. Column 'id'.

So far I was able to write the code for the maximum entries.

```
#Get the first id with the largest dist:
fastmoving.loc[fastmoving['dist'].idxmax(),'id']

#Get all id's with the largest dist:
fastmoving.loc[fastmoving['dist']==fastmoving['dist'].max(),'id']
```

what I miss is to my code to work for more than one value.

1. So instead of the maximum value, to work for a range of maximum values (**top n** values).
2. And then get all the ids that belong with over some **m** percentage in those **n** maximum values.

Can you please help me on how I can achieve that in pandas?

Thanks a lot 
Alex

Comment: Is `id` a percentage ?

Comment: give thresholds to your `n` and `m` and check iteratively within your `df`. So first get all `dist` with `n` greater than or equal to your threshold for n, place them in a list, then use that list as your filter values for your new df. Now in your new df, do the same process again but on the `id` column with condition if `m` is greater than or equal to your m threshold, place in the list, use the list as filter value for the final df. All of the filter part can be done using `isin()` method by the way. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) for **top n** and [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) for **top m%**, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

fastmoving = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
        dist  unique          id
1   0.406677     4.0  4.997434e+09
2   0.406677     4.0  4.452593e+09
5   0.406677     4.0  4.188395e+09
1   0.434386     4.0  8.288070e+09
4   0.434386     4.0  3.274609e+09"""), sep="\s+")

n = 3
m = 50

top_n_dist = fastmoving.nlargest(n, ["dist"])
top_m_precent_id_in_top_n_dist = top_n_dist[top_n_dist['id']>top_n_dist['id'].quantile(m/100)]

print(top_m_precent_id_in_top_n_dist)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can leverage [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html). The following example would take the top **3** values of `dist`, and from that, extract the top **2** values of `id`:

```
fastmoving.nlargest(3, ["dist", "id"]).nlargest(2, "id")
       dist  unique            id
1  0.434386     4.0  8.288070e+09
1  0.406677     4.0  4.997434e+09
```